# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin.Android - limit fling in Image Gallery to just one item per fling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

When I swipe the gallery, multiple images go from right to the left, depending on the swipe speed. Can you please tell me how to limit the swipe to only 1 image at a time, no matter how fast I swipe?

```
[Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);


            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
             SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            Gallery gallery = (Gallery)FindViewById<Gallery>(Resource.Id.gallery);

            gallery.Adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

            gallery.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args) {
                Toast.MakeText(this, args.Position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override the Gallery  `OnFling()` method and don't call the superclass `OnFling()` method.

In this way on swipe the gallery advance one item to time.
This will make the gallery advance one item per swipe.

Edit:
You can create a class ExtendedGallery:

```
public class ExtendedGallery : Gallery
    {
        public ExtendedGallery(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        public override bool OnFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            //return base.OnFling (e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then use `ExtendedGallery` instead of `Gallery`.

Comment: Can you be more sprecific, please?(i.e. I am a beginner, so without a code sample I am lost).

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks! You are my hero today ;) 

I also added more code:

        public ExtendedGallery(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
                : base(javaReference, transfer)
            {
        }
        public ExtendedGallery(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
                : base(context, attrs)
            {
        }
        public ExtendedGallery(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
                : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
            {
        }

Comment: Thanks, you are welcome. Yes i only wrote one costructor. As you have done, you can implements others costructor if you need.